# There were reports of certain countries that had issued their own cryptocurrency. What are they?

Tags: erc-20

I've been reading that certain countries with sanctions has issued their own cryptocurrency on the Ethereum blockchain as ERC20 tokens. What are they and which countries? And are they on any exchanges?

Comment: Venezuela has issued Petros cryptocurrency, but it isn't on Ethereum.